# ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED when using selenium-wire

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I tried to do the usual task to **scrape** data from a website.

Because I found that the data in the website is actually HTTP requests, and I can see the json in the response, I want to **scrape** the json files directly.

Then I found this [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/) which said "Extends Selenium to give you the ability to inspect requests made by the browser."

It works as expected in the first page. I got the json file. But whenever I click the link in the webpage using the webdriver, the connection is broken, saying ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED.

I tried to switch back to selenium. It works again (without the json download).

So, are there any potential problems I can check with? and

Any other way to get the json? (Request seems not working because the websites need log in)

Answer (score 1):

I found out that I'm getting this error if script finished execution. I put time.sleep(1000) at the end of the script. While a script is still running, link clicks and opening new pages work normally.

Answer (score 0):

selenium wire works both for proxy authentication and without it

with authentication

```
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
        'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

without authentication

```
options = {
    'proxy': {
        'http': 'http://host:port',
        'https': 'https://host:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080',
        'custom_authorization': 'Bearer mytoken123'  # Custom Proxy-Authorization header value
    }
}
driver = webdriver.Firefox(seleniumwire_options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
options = {
    'connection_timeout': None,
    'proxy': {

        'http': 'http://username:password@host:port',
        'https': 'https://username:password@host:port',
        'no_proxy': 'localhost,127.0.0.1,dev_server:8080'
    }
}
```

Comment: i added connection_timeout to none

Comment: I think someone should try using seleniumbase

Comment: Please add all such explanation to the answer by editing it